# How to import my own Cython module to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, cython

The problem is I can't import my Cython module to jupyter notebook. I no clues but wonder if this has something to do with **multiple conda envs** I used.

Inside a `cythonDir`, I wrote a `.pyx` file with a single function defined and it was compiled successfully via a `setup.py`. Strangely, I can't import it to my current notebook, which is in the same directory as `cythonDir`. I have **no problem importing the module into an interactive python terminal** under `parentDir` though.

The overall directory tree:

```
- parentDir
  - notebook.ipynb
  - cythonDir
```

One thing to note is that my jupyter is installed in a conda env `proj` and the notebook is running with another kernel (environment) `tf2`. (the cython module is compiled under `tf2`).

I was doing this in order to install a single jupyter and to work with different envs via switching Kernel inside jupyter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you compile your code ? did you try `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`? https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#basic-setup-py

Comment: Thank you @Sylvain for your comment. Yes, I followed the guide but it's not successful.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by my friends, one can write and compile Cython code **in notebook** following [this section](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#using-the-jupyter-notebook).

This is *not* an answer, but rather an alternative method to using customed Cython module in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your setup.py ? If your package starts at parentDir, then try to follow this (it worked for me):

```
+ notebok.ipnb
+ parentDir
L--+ setup.py
   + python_src
   +-- script.py
   + cython_src
   L-- script.pyx
```

You need to be at the same level as the whole package for your notebook to be able to import it.
Let me know if it works.